# C++ System call killing program process (Ubuntu)?

Tags: c++, ubuntu

In my C++ code, I use `system()` to call Ocropus, an OCR cli tool written in python. I deemed it easier to make a few system calls than to look into embedding Python in my code and calling the OCR functions, directly. Anywho,

Shortly into the `system` call of Ocropus (which outputs to stdout as it works), i see "Killed" at which point it returns to my `user@computer:~/path`. But strangely, Ocropus continues to run, to completion. And it cannot be `^C` or `^\` to kill it. I have probably just misunderstood `system()`. Thanks for any help

Example code:

```
system("ocropus-gpageseg -n --maxcolseps 0 col?.png");
```

Output:

```
INFO:  
INFO:  ########## ocropus-gpageseg -n --maxcolseps 0 /image/path/here
INFO:  
INFO:  image/path/here
INFO:  scale 21.0237960416
INFO:  computing segmentation
INFO:  computing column separators
INFO:  computing lines
Killed
user@computer:~/path
INFO:  propagating labels
INFO:  spreading labels
INFO:  number of lines151
INFO:  finding reading order
INFO:  writing lines
...And it continues to completion
```

Comment: you need to write down some code to clarify how you use `system()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are you running low on memory, by any chance?

Comment: Use `dmesg` to find out why it was killed.

Comment: Show the code...are you catching any exception?

Comment: @immibis was right. Thanks to @xvan `dmesg` does report `Out of memory: Killed process XXXXX`. I'll have to re-think my approach, I suppose!